# Data driven tests in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm rewriting some JUnit test into Spock to take advantage of the data driven test style.

I'm struggling a bit with how to provide the verification with something dynamic.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def "domestic rules"(from, to, oneWay, check) {

    expect:
    String mealResponse = getMealResponse(new BookingOptions.BookingOptionsBuilder().setFrom(from).setTo(to).setOneWay(oneWay).build());
    check(mealResponse)

    where:
    from  | to    | oneWay || check
    'MNL' | 'PEK' | true   || assertNoMeals()
}

def assertNoMeals = {
    assert JsonAssert.with(it)
            .assertThat('$.links', hasSize(1))
            .assertThat('$.links[0].rel', is("http://localhost:9001/api/docs/rels/ink/meal-allocations"))
            .assertThat('$.links[0].uri', startsWith("http://localhost:9001/api/tenants/acme/meals/allocations/"));
}
```

Unfortunately, I get a NullPointerException at the line with the first row of data.

I guess thats because the closure is being run at that point, rather than just declared.

Is there a way to do this better?

Comment: You should read the [Spock Primer](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html). You're doing the assertion wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def "domestic rules"() {

  when: 'get meals using certain parameters'
  String mealResponse = getMealResponse(new BookingOptions.BookingOptionsBuilder().setFrom(from).setTo(to).setOneWay(oneWay).build())

  then: 'the json response should contain some contents (improve the message here!)'
  JsonAssert.with(mealResponse)
        .assertThat('$.links', hasSize(1))
        .assertThat('$.links[0].rel', is(somethingToUseInAssertions))


  where:
  from  | to    | oneWay || somethingToUseInAssertions
  'MNL' | 'PEK' | true   || 'just some example'
}
```

The above should help you get in the right track. Notice that you should have some values only in the examples. If you need some logic in the assertions, use a value which indicates what kind of assertion needs to be made... but it's a very bad idea to use a closure as an example.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that allows me to add more rows and have different assertions. Your example is hard coded to one rows assertions.

Comment: Create one test per type of assertion. That's how you do it. If each example has a completely different assertion, then the examples belong in separate features.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as the solution as I've decided to abandon this approach and go with one test per assertion set. I think the data driven style is more suited to consistent inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
def "domestic rules"(from, to, oneWay, check) {
```

To

```
@Unroll
def "domestic rules from #from to #to one way #oneWay"() {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make your test hard to maintain and go ahead and use closures as "values" in your examples, then do something like this:

```
def "domestic rules"() {

  when:
  String mealResponse = getMealResponse(new BookingOptions.BookingOptionsBuilder().setFrom(from).setTo(to).setOneWay(oneWay).build())

  then:
  check(mealResponse)

  where:
  from  | to    | oneWay || check
  'MNL' | 'PEK' | true   || this.&assertNoMeals 
}

boolean assertNoMeals(mealResponse) {
  assert JsonAssert.with(mealResponse)
        .assertThat('$.links', hasSize(1))
        .assertThat('$.links[0].rel',  is("http://localhost:9001/api/docs/rels/ink/meal-allocations"))
        .assertThat('$.links[0].uri',   startsWith("http://localhost:9001/api/tenants/acme/meals/allocations/"))
  return true // pass!
}
```

I advise you to learn both Groovy and Spock before writing something that is more reasonable. It's not hard, but it does take at least a few hours!

Comment: Just found that you actually need to make `assertNoMeals` return a boolean (true) for the test to pass... Spock normally recognizes void methods, but in this case it does not recognize the method reference returns void.

Comment: Not sure why you think this is a bad idea. Parameterized tests are useful, I just have different assertions though they are JSON assertions.

Comment: If you have different assertions, they'd probably be better in different tests